# regex or empty string not working

Tags: regex, xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I am trying to validate an `xml` via an `xsd`.
One of the fields its an optional field, which can contain value or not. In my case, the IP of a computer.
I am checking with `xsd` the expression regular to check that it has IP format, but can't validate when it comes empty.

Here is the [example](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/?save=21a198db-90b5-4954-ac73-0d91976d2605-xsdvalidation#.Vxo2OjCLT4Y)

To validate IP I used following regex:

```
((([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))|($)
```

As you see, I tried to use (the regex for the IP expression) | `($)`
But it does not work with empty string.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?
Thank you all

Comment: empty string is :- `^\s*$`

Comment: Also tried that, and it is not working: http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/?save=a30e536f-4ede-41a8-8a62-6822bdc50319-xsdvalidation#.Vxo3_TCLT4Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in your regex - the unescaped `.` matches any character. You can either escape it or put inside a character class, e.g. `[.]` so that it could only match a literal period (dot). To match an empty string, just add the `?` quantifier at the end:

```
((([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])[.]){3}([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))?
                                               ^^^ (dot inside a char class)                        ^ - The whole pattern can match 1 or 0 times
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nJ0bF7/1)

To also match blank lines, you will need to add an alternative:

```
(\s*|((([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])[.]){3}([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])))
 ^^^^
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nJ0bF7/2)